# How to properly export XML to file using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

Importing any valid XML file as source using `[XML]$Var = Get-Content -Path $PathToAnyValidXML` I am unable to export it's content properly.

Using `Set-Content SomePath $Var` , the file ends with System.Xml.XmlDocument as content.

Using `$Var | Export-Clixml SomePath` , the file ends with the original XML inside an XML

What is a correct method to write raw XML to a file properly ? (Get the exact same content that was on $PathToAnyValidXML once it was imported to a variable on Powershell)

If we need to use XPath or Objects, provide example with both method if possible.

Answer (score 31):

Since you imported the file as an XML Object using [XML], to export it that way you should use the `Save()` Mathod.

```
$VAR.save("c:\works.xml")
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I should have used Import-Clixml in the first place instead of get-content + [XML]$xxx to get the way I was doing it working, correct ?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but yes you're right. import-clixml will import an XML object, that you can work with easily, get-content wont do that for you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 with PowerShell Extensions (`Pscx`) installed, and a convenient way that I found is to do this:

```
$Var | Format-Xml | Out-File $file_path
```

Comment: using Powershell 5.1, and getting the error `"Format-Xml" is not recognized ...`

Comment: Hey @Pac0, I'm sorry I didn't realize at the time, but `Format-Xml` comes from the PowerShell extensions module. I think it's a good idea to install them because they are very useful

Comment: nice thing to know, then ! Thanks for answering

Answer (score -5):

Give `Out-File a try and see if that does what you're after.

```
$Var | Out-File SomePath
```

Comment: `Out-File` doesn't keep formatting on the xml, though.