# How do you format XML output properly from Powershell using invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql, xml, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

Below is my PowerShell script that connects to a remote SQL server and stored the result into a XML file.

```
$SQLResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -inputfile $inputfile -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Username $Username -Password $Password 
$PropertyName = ($SQLResult | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Where {$_.Name -like "XML*"}).Name
$SQLResult.$PropertyName | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\ExportFile.xml" -Force
```

Ideally it should return sth clean and neat like this (Which is also the case when I open up the result in my SQL Server Management Studio):

```
<Text>
    <Data>I am happy</Data>
</Text>
```

However, when I open the file, it gives me:

```
<Text><Data>I am happy</Data></Text>
```

I have tried to use `Export-Clixml`, but the XML returned is surrounded by some meaningless tags called `<props>` which is not one of my tags.

Can anyone help me out on this, not sure which way to go to save it in its original format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830917/how-to-properly-export-xml-to-file-using-powershell

Answer (score 2):

Use an `XmlWriter` to format and indent it nicely when writing back to disk:

```bsh
# Create settings object, make sure we get the indentation
$writerSettings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new()
$writerSettings.Indent = $true

try{
  # Create the writer
  $writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\Temp\ExportFile.xml", $writerSettings)

  # Convert your XML string to an XmlDocument, 
  # then save the document using the writer
  ([xml]$SQLResult.$PropertyName).Save($writer)
}
finally {
  # discard writer (closes the file handle as well)
  $writer.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns an error: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'>' is an unexpected token. The
expected token is '='. Line 3, position 3."

Comment: @David Sounds like whatever string value `$SQLResult.$PropertyName` resolved to isn't valid XML :)

Comment: Is there a way to see if anything is wrong with my XML file :( rly have no clue

Comment: @David If you just print/output the value of `$SQLResult.$Property` to the screen, what's on line 3?

Comment: PS C:\Users\David Kao> $SQLResult.$Property
PS C:\Users\David Kao>